# jquery container property with parents method

Tags: jquery, css

In below line of code

```
 $(field.container).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
```

what does "container"  mean.  Is it a jquery property? what does it do?

Comment: a variable most probobly

Comment: it may contain a selector or an HTML string....... anyway it's up to your code

Comment: its a class name for element field. field maybe any element inside your page. like $("div.container").parents('...')....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this context the value inside the jquery selector `$()` is the selector.

So either `field` is a variable, and container a child of it, or possibly another form of selector, meaning its searching for DOM element of type "field" and applying class filter ".container" for html class "container" (similar to css)

It could even be a typo, with quotation marks left out, unlikely though as you didnt mention any bugs.

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

`jQuery( "element" )` https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

`jQuery( ".class" )` https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

so:

```
jQuery("element.class");
```